# Javascript refresh time in HTML text box; getElementByID error

Tags: javascript, date, getelementbyid

I am trying to have the time display every second in an HTML page, in a text box, but I just get the error message that getElementByID does not exist.  My code is below. Nothing displays with the code below.  can you please correct me, or point out what I am missing?

```
function getTime() {
     var currentDate = new Date();
     var date = currentDate.toLocaleString();
     document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = date;
}

var repeatedTime = setInterval("getTime()", 1000);
getTime();
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="clockjavascript.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="clock" type="text" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you to Daniel Szabo, for he solved this problem.  The correct javascript which works with the HTML is below.  I needed to change document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML to .value.

```
function getTime() {
    var dateObject = new Date();
    var dateString = dateObject.toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById("clock").value = dateString;
}

var repeatedTime = setInterval(getTime, 1000);
getTime();
```

Comment: change ID -> Id

Comment: It's [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). The `d` is lowercase.

Comment: I changed it to document.getElementByID and it still does not work.

Comment: Try `setInterval(getTime, 1000);`
instead of `setInterval("getTime()", 1000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four issues

- Use `getElementById` instead of getElementByID  ("d" needs to be lowercase")
- Use `document.getElementById("clock").value` instead of `innerHTML` to manipulate the contents of a textbox
- Try `setInterval(getTime, 1000);` instead of `setInterval("getTime()", 1000);`
- Move the `<script src="clockjavascript.js"></script>` tag to the bottom of the page, just before the `</body>` tag.  That way the `<input>` element being acted upon is rendered and available to be acted upon when the script executes.

For a quick test, you can paste this into your browser console and watch the time tick away.

```
function getTime() {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var date = currentDate.toLocaleString();
   console.log(date);
}

var repeatedTime = setInterval(getTime, 1000);
getTime();
```

Comment: I tried both of those changes the web page still does not load the time

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is nothing happening at all?

Comment: "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" is the error

Comment: @Gideon Ok that's good progress.  That means the script can't find the element with an id named "clock".  Try moving your script tag to the bottom of the document, just before the </body> tag.  That way, the input element has had a chance to render before the javascript engine tries to find it. :)

Comment: Thank you; the final code for the javascript is here.  What helped was the document.getElementById("clock").value.  I needed the value part instead of innerHTML.  function getTime() {
 var currentDate = new Date();
 var date = currentDate.toLocaleString();
 document.getElementById("clock").value = date;
}

var repeatedTime = setInterval(getTime, 1000);
getTime();

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is slightly off - it's

```
getElementById
```

Rather than

```
getElementByID
```

The latter doesn't exist as a method.

Comment: As per the above comments, the d is lowercase in Id.